# GCP Dataflow is unable to access BigQuery dataset in a different GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a GCP dataflow which reads two datasets in two different GCP projects and compare them.

It works fine for two datasets in the same project. However, when I tried to compare two datasets in different projects, I got an error:

```
{
  "message": "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to confirm BigQuery dataset presence for table \"my-other-project:my_dataset_other.2022-07-13_My_BigQuery_Table\". If the dataset is created by an earlier stage of the pipeline, this validation can be disabled using #withoutValidation.",
  "stacktrace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to confirm BigQuery dataset presence for table \"my-other-project:my_dataset_other.2022-07-13_My_BigQuery_Table\". If the dataset is created by an earlier stage of the pipeline, this validation can be disabled using #withoutValidation.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.validate(BigQueryIO.java:1018)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$ValidateVisitor.enterCompositeTransform(Pipeline.java:662)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:581)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.validate(Pipeline.java:598)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)\n\tat ....
  org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\n\tat 
  ........
  
  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers.verifyDatasetPresence(BigQueryHelpers.java:521)\n\t... 116 more\nCaused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden\nGET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-other-project/datasets/my_dataset_other?prettyPrint=false\n{\n  \"code\" : 403,\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"domain\" : \"global\",\n    \"message\" : \"Access Denied: Dataset my-other-project:my_dataset_other: Permission bigquery.datasets.get denied on dataset my-other-project:my_dataset_other (or it may not exist).\",\n    \"reason\" : \"accessDenied\"\n  } ],\n  \"message\" : \"Access Denied: Dataset my-other-project:my_dataset_other: Permission bigquery.datasets.get denied on dataset my-other-project:my_dataset_other (or it may not exist).\",\n  \"status\" : \"PERMISSION_DENIED\"\n}\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:428)\n\tat com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)\n\tat com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.executeWithRetries(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1324)\n\t... 118 more\n"
}
Response headers
 cache-control: no-cacheno-storemax-age=0must-revalidate 
 connection: close 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Wed20 Jul 2022 13:40:30 GMT 
 expires: 0 
 pragma: no-cache
```

This error happens when the dataflow pipeline that runs on ProjectA tries to access data in my-other-project:my_dataset_other. The dataflow runs using a service account my_user@projecta.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

I have given this service account a role of "BigData Data Viewer" on my-other-project:my_dataset_other.

**EDIT:**

The code is something like this:

```
private PCollection<MyModel> readModelFromBigQuery(Pipeline pipeline, String projectId, String datasetId, String table) {
    var tableReference = new TableReference()
            .setProjectId(projectId)
            .setDatasetId(datasetId)
            .setTableId(table);

    return pipeline
            .apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(tableReference ))
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(MyModel.class)).via(MyModel::fromTableRow));
}



var pCollection1 = readModelFromBigQuery(pipeline, "my-first-project", "my_dataset_first", "2022-07-13_My_BigQuery_Table");
var pCollection2 = readModelFromBigQuery(pipeline, "my-other-project", "my_dataset_other", "2022-07-13_My_BigQuery_Table");

PCollectionList.of(pCollection1).and(pCollection2)
            .apply(new MyTransformation())
            .apply(BigQueryIO.<MyModel>write()
                .to(composeDestinationTableName())
.......
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Can you also share your Beam code?

Comment: hard to say without code.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added my code.

Comment: @hlagos I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easier than expected! My eyes felt on the 403 forbidden error today and you miss the biquery.datasets.get permission.

Of course, for getting the data, you only need to be BQ data viewer on the dataset, but, obviously, the Beam connector first list the datasets, and then query the data in the datasets. So, you have to grant the capacity to list the datasets at project level.

It's a bad new for least privilege principle, but simply grant your service account at project level. To limit the scope of the permissions, you can grant the role [roles/bigquery.metadataViewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) at project level. It's not too wide, and not dangerous at all (better than data viewer at project scope)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I grant the role bigquery.metadataviewer to the service account I used to run Dataflow "at the dataset level", not the project level. It does not seem to work. Do I have to set it at the project level? Also, I cannot find a role with name bigquery.datasets.get. What did I do wrong.

Comment: I understand your wish of least privilege concern but, wait a minutes and think about the process. Dataflow use the credential and check if the project exist. If so, checks if the dataset exists in the project. If so, query the table in the dataset. For the latest permission, you are in the dataset and you can put the permission at Dataset level. But this one before, Dataflow has to check if the dataset exists in the project, so you have to grant the role at project level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. I will try this. Which role shall I grant? Just the roles/bigquery.metadataViewer?

Comment: Yes, At project level, grant only this one, it should be enough. Then keep your best practice to narrow the permissions to the lower level of resource! (the dataset here)